# Export content to pdf angular using jspdf

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am trying to create a pdf using jspdf. However I'm getting error `cannot create property 'header' on string 'Details'`.I went through this question [How to fix: Cannot create property 'header' on string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55965954/how-to-fix-cannot-create-property-header-on-string) but couldn't find a solution.Please Help.Thanks in advance.
Here is my convert function

```
convert() {

    var doc = new jsPDF();
    var col = ["Details", "Values"];
    var rows = [];

    /* The following array of object as response from the API req  */

    var itemNew = [
      { id: 'Case Number', name: '101111111' },
      { id: 'Patient Name', name: 'UAT DR' },
      { id: 'Hospital Name', name: 'Dr Abcd' }
    ];


    itemNew.forEach(element => {
      var temp = [element.id, element.name];
      rows.push(temp);

    });

    doc.autoTable(col, rows);
    doc.save('Test.pdf');
  }
```

StackBLitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jspdf-xgoetc?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Can you share in stackbiltz

Comment: @AdritaSharma added stackblitz link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `autoTable()` function where you specify`head` and `body`.

```
var col = [["Details", "Values"]];
```

alter `autoTable()` like

```
 doc.autoTable({
        head: col,
        body: rows
    });
```

Updated Snippet:

```
convert() {

    var doc = new jsPDF();
    var col = [["Details", "Values"]];
    var rows = [];

    /* The following array of object as response from the API req  */

    var itemNew = [
      { id: 'Case Number', name: '101111111' },
      { id: 'Patient Name', name: 'UAT DR' },
      { id: 'Hospital Name', name: 'Dr Abcd' }
    ];


    itemNew.forEach(element => {
      var temp = [element.id, element.name];
      rows.push(temp);

    });

    //doc.autoTable(col, rows);
    doc.autoTable({
        head: col,
        body: rows
    });
    doc.save('Test.pdf');
  }
```

PDF Preview (Test.pdf):

[image: PDF Preview]

Refer to the [jsPDF-AutoTable Documentation](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable) for more info.

Comment: @rock11 Glad to help. Could you please mark the answer as useful. Thank you